# Fechar um jInternalFrame antes de Abrir outro

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou fazendo um projeto de navegador (onde eu mesmo crio as "páginas" no design do netbeans - *Tudo offline*) apenas para aprender nas férias. Porém estou com uma dúvida, acredito que seja simples mas como estou iniciando ainda estou tentando entender a lógica.

Eu tenho um `jTextFieldPesquisa` e nele a pessoa irá digitar o site que ela deseja abrir e tenho um botão na frente que quando clicado, ele irá abrir a tela do site. (Futuramente ainda vou fazer sem o jButton, mas no inicio achei melhor separar para eu entender o funcionamento dos dois).

**Segue um exemplo do meu jButtonEnterActionPerformed:**

```
    if((jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("www.facebook.com.br")) || (jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("facebook.com.br")) || (jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("31.13.85.36"))) {

        Facebook obj1=new Facebook();
        jDesktopPaneBG.add(obj1);
        try{
            obj1.setMaximum(true);
            obj1.setVisible(true);
            obj1.setPosicao();

        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
        }

    }
```

Nesse if acima, quando o usuário clica no `jTextFieldPesquisa` e da **enter**, a página que eu criei do facebook irá aparecer dentro do `jDesktopPane`.
Vale salientar que estou usando um `jTabbedPane` para abrir um `jInternalFrame` e nesse jInternalFrame é aberta a página em si.

**O problema:** 
Quando eu abro uma página (www.facebook.com.br), e logo depois digito (www.google.com.br) que foi outra página que eu desenhei no jInternalFrame. **A página google fica em cima da página facebook. Eu gostaria de esconder a página do facebook antes de abrir a do google.**

No começo a minha lógica seria inserir uma variável publica booleana iniciando com falsa e toda vez que entrasse dentro do if, ela seria true. Então, eu saberia que essa página estaria aberta porque ela tem o valor true, eu teria que fechá-la primeiro para abrir outra. Até aí tudo bem (na minha lógica).

Dai eu precisava saber o valor do objeto da tela que estava aberta. Como para cada tela, eu instanciei um obj1, obj2, obj3 eu apenas criei uma variável publica também inteira iniciada com 0. Cada vez que entrasse naquele if, essa variável iria guardar o "valor do objeto" e então eu saberia qual instancia do objeto estava aberta e poderia fechá-la antes de abrir a outra.

**Ficaria assim:**

public boolean pagina = false;
public int numObjeto = 0;

```
    if((jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("www.facebook.com.br")) || (jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("facebook.com.br")) || (jTextFieldPesquisa.getText().equals("31.13.85.36"))) {

        Facebook obj1=new Facebook();
        jDesktopPaneBG.add(obj1);
        try{
            obj1.setMaximum(true);
            obj1.setVisible(true);
            obj1.setPosicao();

            pagina = true;  //pagina esta aberta
            numObjeto = 1; //igual obj1
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
        }

    }
```

Se alguém quiser ver o projeto, ele está no github [marciellioliveira](https://github.com/marciellioliveira/Navegador)

Comment: Não pode reaproveitar a mesma tela com a nova pagina? Talvez seja mais facil.

Comment: Então, mas como eu faria isso com o jTabbedPane? Porque a intenção seria abrir igual a do chrome, por exemplo. :/

Comment: Já tentou adicionar uma nova tab no tabbedpane? `seutabbedPane.add("aqui você adiciona um painel")`

Comment: Sim, mas vamos supor que a pessoa ta usando o facebook, não quer mais usar, clica no textfield da mesma página que o facebook está e digita google. Dai queria "imitar" isso, sabe? Porque dai quando ela der o enter vai sumir o facebook e abrir o google.

Comment: E dai quando a pessoa clicar na nova guia, dai sim eu posso adicionar a nova tab, acredito eu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consegui resolver....
// o jInternalFrame é pra ser exibido dentro de um JDesktopPane o meu se chama Desktop..
// criei um metodo para fechar a tela que esta ativa no momento...

private void disposeOnClosed() {

```
JInternalFrame tela = Desktop.getSelectedFrame();
if (tela==null){}
else{
Desktop.getSelectedFrame().dispose();
}   
}
```

//no evento que chama a tela eu coloquei o evento que chama o metodo:

private void jMenu1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

```
disposeOnClosed();
TelaGerencia gerencia = new TelaGerencia();
gerencia.setVisible(true);
Desktop.add(gerencia);

}
```

funcionou perfeitamente, espero ter ajudado!!!